Understanding Proof of Compactness Hilbert Cubes in l2
I'm trying to prove that Hilbert cube is compact in $\langle \ell^2,  \|\cdot \|_2\rangle$
My proof so far:
Let $x \in \ell^2$. $x(k)$ denotes the $k$-th term of $x$.
Let $\{x_n\} \subset H$ where $H$ is the Hilbert cube. By the definition of Hilbert cube, $|x_n(k)| \le \frac{1}{k}$, therefore $\{x_n(k)\}_n$ bounded. Because it's bounded there exists a subsequence $\{x_{m_{(k, j)}}(k)\}_j \subset\{x_n(k)\}_n$ converging to $y_k$
Let
$\{a_n\} =\{x_{n_k}\}_k$
, where $n_k = m_{(k, k)}$. I want to show that $a_n \rightarrow y = (\ y_1,\ y_2, \ y_3, \ \cdots \ )$.
From the Cauchy criterion, I have shown that
\begin{align*}
d_2\left(a_n, y_n\right)^2 \le\sum_{k=1}^{N_1-1} \left(a_n(k) - y_n(k) \right)^2 + 4 \epsilon
\end{align*}
I am a bit stuck here so from what I read in
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hilbert_Cube_is_Compact/2-Sequence_Space_with_2-Norm
for the first summation, we want to show that $\forall k < N_1: a_n(k) \rightarrow y_n$
I don't understand how is $\{m_{(k, k)}\}_k$ subsequence of $\{m_{(N_1,k)}\}_k$ or did I misinterpreted it?

I prefer a proof in the second part of this answer. A direct proof could be as follows. Let $x_n$ be a sequence of elements in the cube. As each numerical sequence $x_n(k)$ is bounded (by $k^{-1})$ then applying the diagonal method there is a subsequence of indices $n_m$ so that each sequence $x_{n_m}(k)$ is convergent, say to $y(k).$ Then $|y(k)|\le k^{-1}.$ Hence $y$ belongs to the cube. It remains  to show that $\|x_{n_m}-y\|_2\to 0.$ Fix a natural number $K.$ There is $M$ such that $|x_{n_m}(k)-y(k)|<K^{-2}$ for $m>M$
and $k\le K.$ Then for $m>M$ we get $$\|x_{n_m}-y\|_2^2=\sum_{k=1}^K|x_{n_m}(k)-y(k)|^2+\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty |x_{n_m}(k)-y(k)|^2\\ \le K\cdot K^{-2}+\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty {4\over k^2}\le K^{-1}+ 4K^{-1}=5K^{-1}$$
Consider the operator $T:\ell^\infty \to \ell^2$ defined  by $$ (Tx)(k)={1\over k}x(k)$$ The operator is bounded as $$\|Tx\|_2^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2}|x(k)|^2\le \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2}\right )\,\|x\|_\infty^2 $$ Moreover the operator $T$ is compact since the finite dimensional operators $$(T_n)(k)=\begin{cases} {1\over k}x(k) &1\le k\le n\\ 0&k>n\end{cases}$$ satisfy $$\|T_n-T\|^2\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1\over k^2}\to 0$$Observe that $T(B_1)$ is the Hilbert cube, where $B_1$ denotes the closed unit ball in $\ell^\infty .$ Hence the Hilbert cube is relatively compact. On the other hand the Hilbert cube is closed in $\ell^2$ as $$|x(k)-y(k)|\le \|x-y\|_2$$ Therefore it is compact.
Remark The proof cna be applied when the sequence $k^{-1}$ is replaced by any square summable sequence $a(k).$
